# Downgrading Cordova version 9.0.0 to 8.1.2 is not working

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been trying to deploy my Cordova app to iOS Testflight but each time I do, the debug is telling me the plugins are not found. Therefore I tried to re-install cordova using npm uninstall and then npm install, followed by `cordova add platform iOS`, but each time I do I receive the following error message: `Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "q" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it`.

I have read around that downgrading from Cordova 9.0.0 to 8.1.2 can fix this problem, so I again ran `npm uninstall cordova` followed by `npm install -g cordova@8.1.2` but when I then check the Cordova version using `cordova -v` it still comes back saying `9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)`. I have tried using `$ sudo` as well but I still get the same result

To give some context, this is a fairly old project with quite a few deprecations. I am just trying to get it on TestFlight again without making massive changes. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

try uninstalling cordova 9.0.0 by following command in your terminal:

sudo npm uninstall -g cordova

Then install 8.1.2 by:

sudo npm install -g cordova@8.1.2

Hope this helps...